# Eleições para Moderador 2015 - Coleção de Perguntas

Tags: debate, eleição

> **O objetivo deste post era coletar as perguntas que fariam parte do nosso questionário para os candidatos. Você pode acompanhar as respostas [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3950/12).**

Como parte da eleição, temos uma sessão de perguntas e respostas com os candidatos. É a oportunidade da comunidade de entender melhor como os candidatos pensam a respeito da moderação do site. A participação é voluntária.

Como funciona:

- Durante a fase de indicação, (até 15/06/2015 às 20:00:00Z UTC; 17:00 Brasília; 21:00 Lisboa) essa pergunta ficará aberta para que vocês enviem suas perguntas aos candidatos. Basta responder esse post com a sua pergunta. Mas apenas *uma pergunta por post!*
- Nós, da Equipe de Comunidades, também temos algumas genéricas para os candidatos de todas as eleições. Dentre essas, as duas primeiras vão ser incluídas na lista final. O resto só será utilizado se a comunidade não enviar um número suficiente de perguntas. Nossas perguntas serão colocadas todas em uma resposta a esse post.
- Aproveitem essa oportunidade para perguntar sobre os temas que te interessam sobre a moderação e os desafios enfrentados pela comunidade.
- Ao final dessa fase, serão escolhidas **no máximo 8 entre as peguntas mais votadas aqui**, que serão utilizadas junto das outras 2 perguntas padrão. Nos reservamos o direito editorial sobre as perguntas enviadas pela comunidade, e podemos não escolher perguntas que julgarmos irrelevantes à eleição. Dito isso, se alguma pergunta apresentar problemas, nós vamos falar a respeito nos comentários.
- Depois que as perguntas forem escolhidas, elas serão listadas em um novo tópico no Meta, com o questionário para os candidatos. Serão 10 perguntas no total.
- Essa não é a única oportunidade que a comunidade tem de conhecer melhor os candidatos. Vocês podem, por exemplo, organizar debates públicos no chat da eleição ou conversar mais a fundo sobre os temas discutidos no questionário.

Caso tenham mais perguntas, ou sugestões, sobre como funciona o questionário, basta comentar aqui.

Comment: As perguntas devem ser respondidas pelos candidatos durante as Primárias?

Comment: @Math Sim. O questionário final vai pro Meta assim que começarem as Primárias

Comment: Atuei como repórter chato e fiz várias perguntas aos candidatos, principalmente sobre a "fila de analise", espero que ajude o pessoal decidir em quem votar :)

Comment: @Gabe acho que esquecemos de fazer essa etapa esse ano, não? :/

Answer (score 26):

Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦ para fazer o que você propôs em sua candidatura?

Comment: Grande pergunta! :)

Comment: Esta me deixou a pensar...

Comment: Excelente pergunta

Comment: Uma pergunta que responde muitas perguntas.

Answer (score 19):

Como você vê a qualidade das perguntas e respostas do site hoje? Enquanto moderador, como pretende atuar para manter a qualidade (se achar que está satisfatória), ou melhorá-la (se achar que isso é necessário)?

Answer (score 16):

**Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?**

Acho essa pergunta pertinente porque já vi casos de perguntas que embora fossem de má qualidade, acabam sendo fechadas ou recebendo votos contrários sem maiores explicações para quem fez a pergunta, e o autor da pergunta fica sem orientação. Também acho importante frisar que muitas vezes os novos usuários não conseguem entender o texto dos comentários enlatados, seja porque ele é genérico e impessoal demais ou porque ele parece estar fora do contexto.

Comment: É uma pergunta bem pertinente, das melhores até agora.

Answer (score 15):

Uma pergunta é feita e recebe algumas respostas muito boas, o *AP* sinaliza a pergunta e pede para que ela seja *excluída*, pois pode-lhe causar problemas no local onde ele estuda ou no trabalho.

O que você faz?

Comment: Rapaz, que pergunta delicada (e bacana). :) Sugiro só mudar pra "O que você faz?" ao invés de "Você irá excluir a pergunta?", pois dá liberdade para respostas com outras linhas de pensamento.

Answer (score 14):

Este é um conjunto de perguntas genéricas, que aparecem constantemente em todas as eleições na rede. Conforme dito acima, as duas primeiras perguntas sempre fazem parte do questionário final. As outras serão utilizadas caso não tenhamos perguntas suficientes vindas da comunidade.
É permitido enviar uma dessas perguntas como sua, para ser votada pela comunidade, caso você deseje que ela faça parte do questionário final.

- Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?
- Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

---

- Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?
- Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas, respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?
- De que maneiras você acredita que pode ajudar o site, como moderador, que não seriam possíveis com os privilégios de 10 ou 20 mil?

Comment: Todas as perguntas são boas, mas essa quarta questão... Faz pensar...

Comment: @LucasMotta Se quiser, envie a quarta pergunta aqui. Atualmente ela não vai fazer parte do questionário final

Answer (score 13):

Pode ser a pergunta mais tola, mas eu gostaria de saber:

**Qual é o período de tempo que você pretende moderar diariamente?**

Não vou dizer que é fuso horário, porque a maioria do público está no Brasil e em Portugal. Mas seria interessante ter moderadores que estão operando em horários diferentes.

Comment: Em qual período ou qual a periodicidade? só para evitar dúvidas na pergunta.

Comment: Concordo que não é uma pergunta muita clara. Quero ver como os candidatos vão responder. **Quero que cada um responda do jeito que achar melhor. Não quero que vire uma disputa de quem promete dedicar mais horas.** Quero saber em qual hora do dia estarão moderando, mas não é o fator mais importante no meu voto.

Answer (score 13):

**Um novo usuário posta uma pergunta extremamente confusa, rapidamente fechada pela comunidade, após alguns comentários explicando a ele o problema. O usuário, furioso, reclama no Meta, dizendo que aqui tem regras demais, que somos uns babacas filhos-duma-égua, mandando todo mundo pra aquele lugar. Como você reagiria?**

O assunto é parecido com o [desta pergunta do Victor Stafusa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3910), mas a abordagem é um pouco diferente.

Comment: Sério que essas coisas acontecem? :P

Comment: Não, imagina, é uma questão totalmente hipotética...

Comment: @Math Mesmo *nunca* acontecendo, é bom estar preparado. Vai que um dia acontece! ;)

Comment: É mesmo, eu nem comecei assim nem nada :D Lembra @bfavaretto

Answer (score 11):

Caso eleito, você pretende aumentar sua participação no Meta ou você já a considera satisfatória?

Caso sua resposta seja que vai aumentá-la, por favor explique por que esperar se tornar um moderador para começar a interagir com a comunidade sobre as questões que definem os rumos do site? Por que já não o fez desde sempre?

Caso sua resposta seja que já a considera satisfatória, por favor justifique. Se possível, com exemplos de sua partipação que considera que merecem destaque.

Comment: Excelente pergunta @Math.

Answer (score 9):

Hoje em dia, eu tenho lido/visto em vários locais o uso da expressão **soft skills**. 
*"soft skills pode ser definido como um conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas"*

 Diante disso, qual/quais *soft skills* você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?

Answer (score 8):

**Qual é o conjunto de tags que você visita com mais frequência e quais os tipos de perguntas que você está mais propenso e capacitado a responder?**

Acho que esta pergunta é importante porque acho que os moderadores tem que ter um conhecimento ao menos razoável sobre aquilo que eles moderam, de forma a poder julgar o que é on-topic ou off-topic, o que é uma pergunta duplicada ou apenas parecida e também para saber como os moderadores podem ajudar a comunidade também como usuários normais. Além disso, uma vez que o escopo do SOpt é muito abrangente e diversificado e não dá para uma única pessoa ter conhecimento razoável sobre tudo, é importante que tenhamos moderadores com conhecimentos diversificados na área de tecnologia e programação.

Answer (score 5):

Já me deparei aqui no SOpt com comentários muito bem elaborados em algumas perguntas, comentários que demonstravam que os autores tinham um bom conhecimento sobre o tema em questão. Não obstante o domínio e conhecimento demonstrados, muitos desses comentários não foram efetivados, ou seja, não se transformaram em respostas.

Diante do fato citado acho necessária alguma medida que possa estimular o "usuário/comentador" a ser um "usuário/solucionador".

**Você tem alguma ideia de como instigar um usuário ou auxiliá-lo de forma a fazer um comentário, inteligente, bem elaborado, se tornar uma resposta? Se, sim, como o faria?**

Comment: Um exemplo do quão importante é a presença do moderador no acompanhamento das discussões que circundam um pergunta pode ser visto na questão http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67867/validar-atributo-do-tipo-array-em-uma-anota%C3%A7%C3%A3o. Parece-me que quem comentou na questão tem conhecimento suficiente para uma boa resposta, mas precisa de uma "orientação superior".

Answer (score 4):

**Você é a favor de adotar a política de ser mais (ou menos) rígido de acordo com a reputação?**

De quem tem mais reputação, será cobrado mais. De quem tem menos, será cobrado menos.

Answer (score 4):

**Irá atuar com foco em alguma coisa (se sim qual será o foco) ou irá moderar conforme as coisas vão acontecendo?**

Answer (score 2):

O novo moderador acredita que deve dedicar quanto tempo semanal para moderação do site, e como este tempo deve ser dividido?

Comment: Não é basicamente a mesma pergunta do Marcos?

Comment: como o @marcoszolnowski deixou a pergunta dele ampla, achei válido postar minha versão da pergunta dentro do que gostaria especificamente de consultar aos candidatos.
Como as perguntas são votadas e apenas 8 serão escolhidas dentre as mais.

Answer (score 2):

Você como moderador compreende as implicações políticas e profissionais do cargo?

Answer (score 2):

**O que irá fazer como primeiras medidas assim que receber os poderes de moderador?**

Answer (score 1):

Essa é das questões genéricas, mas achei bem interessante, faz pensar:

> Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado
>   do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas,
>   respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser
>   visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?

Answer (score 0):

Uma pergunta bem complicada, analise cuidadosamente:

*Explique se a pergunta [Muitas telas ou uma tela com muitas informações?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56308/64) deveria ser fechada ou não?*

A história dessa questão é a seguinte:

1. Uma pergunta objetiva e clara foi feita
2. O autor da pergunta decide aumentar a amplitude da pergunta
3. Quando confrontado, o autor reconhece que nenhuma resposta pode responder a pergunta. Ou seja, uma pergunta impossível de responder.

Na minha mente, surgiu todo tipo de dúvidas:

- Existe um jeito de salvar essa pergunta?
- Deveria ser fechada por ser ampla, ou por qual outro motivo?
- A pergunta original ainda é interessante, devo criar uma nova? Mas e se ela for considerada duplicada?
- Será que é caso de favoritismo? Se o autor não fosse uns dos top 10, seria tratado diferente? Porque recebeu vários votos, e foi editada, mas parece que só eu vejo algo de errado nela.
- O autor contribui muito, é estimado por muitos, seria prudente fechar? Não só a reputação do autor pode ser atingida, mas o risco de perder um valioso integrante.
- Será que o autor agiu de má-fé, apenas para ganhar pontos?
- Não é a primeira vez que vejo esse tipo de pergunta no StackOverflow. Será que é assim mesmo que as coisas são?

Pergunto:
**Como você agiria neste caso específico?**

Comment: Eu gostei da pergunta (isto é, acho importante saber o que um candidato a moderador pensa a respeito). Mas, na verdade, são várias perguntas né? Talvez fosse melhor separá-las em mais de uma. E também, para evitar de atrair atenção para uma única pergunta/AP real (até porque há também outras/outros que geraram as mesmas discussões), talvez fosse melhor deixar a pergunta genérica. Por exemplo, acho muito boas (mesmo!) as partes "será que é caso de favoritismo?" e "agiu de má-fé, apenas para ganhar votos", porque permitem à comunidade "conhecer" a linha de pensamento do candidato.

Comment: E se quiser manter o exemplo real, ainda assim acho que dá pra encontrar "casos específicos" ilustrativos para cada um dos seus bullets. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira na verdade a pergunta dele é só uma "Como você agiria neste caso específico?", as outras são o contexto do porquê que ele está perguntando isso. A primeira versão da pergunta dele deixou muita gente confusa, se você ver no histórico de revisões poderá ter uma ideia. Tinham vários comentário aqui que foram apagados, que acho que poderiam te ajudar a entender o contexto. Mas suas observações são pertinentes.

Comment: Ah, desculpem, eu não havia percebido. Obrigado pelo aviso @Math. Bom, ainda assim eu acho que há no mínimo duas ou três ótimas perguntas dentro dessa que talvez fossem mais fáceis de serem respondidas pelos candidatos se fossem separadas (mesmo que mantendo o exemplo específico). Aliás, acho que o Marcos até [já começou a separar uma](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3926/73).

Comment: @LuizVieira eu precisei individualizar as perguntas: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3926/64 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3927/64

Answer (score 0):

**Você irá tratar todos os membros da mesma maneira?**

Sem favorecer certas pessoas, ou desprezar outras.

Comment: A pergunta é boa, se a resposta fosse com garantia de sempre verdade, só que acho que todos irão falar que irão tratar todos iguais, é meio que um tiro no escuro se você não conhecer bem o seu candidato, nesse caso eu dou uma pesquisada (fusada) na no que ele já fez por aqui

Comment: Concordo com o @SneepSNinjA. Talvez essa pergunta possa ser melhorada com uma ilustração de cenário (nem precisa ser real), como quando o AP é usuário com alta pontuação - se essa foi a sua idea no momento de escrita, claro. Aliás, vide o meu comentário sobre separar alguns bullets da sua outra sugestão de pergunta.

Comment: @LuizVieira Esta pergunta tem como contexto  http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3913/64 Mas eu precisei individualizar as perguntas.