# Eleições para Moderador 2016 - Coleção de Perguntas

Tags: debate, eleição

> **O objetivo deste post era coletar as perguntas que fariam parte do nosso questionário para os candidatos. Você pode acompanhar as respostas [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5215).**

Como parte da eleição, temos uma sessão de perguntas e respostas com os candidatos. É a oportunidade da comunidade de entender melhor como os candidatos pensam a respeito da moderação do site. A participação é voluntária.

Como funciona:

- Essa pergunta ficará aberta até o fim da fase primária (até 29/07/2016 às 20:00:00Z UTC; 17:00 Brasília; 21:00 Lisboa) para que vocês enviem suas perguntas aos candidatos. Basta responder esse post com a sua pergunta. Mas apenas *uma pergunta por post!*
- Nós, da Equipe de Comunidades, também temos algumas genéricas para os candidatos de todas as eleições. Dentre essas, as duas primeiras vão ser incluídas na lista final. O resto só será utilizado se a comunidade não enviar um número suficiente de perguntas. Nossas perguntas serão colocadas todas em uma resposta a esse post.
- Aproveitem essa oportunidade para perguntar sobre os temas que te interessam sobre a moderação e os desafios enfrentados pela comunidade.
- Ao final dessa fase, serão escolhidas **no máximo 8 entre as peguntas mais votadas aqui**, que serão utilizadas junto das outras 2 perguntas padrão. Nos reservamos o direito editorial sobre as perguntas enviadas pela comunidade, e podemos não escolher perguntas que julgarmos irrelevantes à eleição. Dito isso, se alguma pergunta apresentar problemas, nós vamos falar a respeito nos comentários.
- Depois que as perguntas forem escolhidas, elas serão listadas em um novo tópico no Meta, com o questionário para os candidatos. Serão 10 perguntas no total.
- Essa não é a única oportunidade que a comunidade tem de conhecer melhor os candidatos. Vocês podem, por exemplo, organizar debates públicos no chat da eleição ou conversar mais a fundo sobre os temas discutidos no questionário.
- Sinto muito pelo tempo reduzido para envio de perguntas. Por falha minha esse post acabou esquecido, mas acredito que ainda podemos fazer um bom trabalho com as perguntas de vocês. Os candidatos terão toda a fase final da eleição para elaborar suas respostas. Como inspiração, podem dar uma olhada nas [perguntas do ano passado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3886).

Caso tenham mais perguntas, ou sugestões, sobre como funciona o questionário, basta comentar aqui.

Answer (score 10):

Este é um conjunto de perguntas genéricas, que aparecem constantemente em todas as eleições na rede. Conforme dito acima, as duas primeiras perguntas sempre fazem parte do questionário final. As outras serão utilizadas caso não tenhamos perguntas suficientes vindas da comunidade.
É permitido enviar uma dessas perguntas como sua, para ser votada pela comunidade, caso você deseje que ela faça parte do questionário final.

- Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?
- Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

---

- Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?
- Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas, respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?
- De que maneiras você acredita que pode ajudar o site, como moderador, que não seriam possíveis com os privilégios de 10 ou 20 mil?

Answer (score 9):

É fato conhecido que um moderador agrega tarefas adicionais ao seu uso normal do Stack Overflow. Duas possíveis consequências são:

1. Diminuição no tempo despendido em perguntas e respostas para dar conta das tarefas de moderador.
2. Aumento do tempo total despendido no site, com subsequente desgaste e diminuição geral na participação do site.

O que você acha mais provável de acontecer com você, por quê e como você pretende lidar com isto?

<sub>NOTA: sei que são várias perguntas, mas eu acho que fiz um ótimo trabalho fazendo parecer uma só. :P</sub>

Comment: Gostei da nota :D

Answer (score 7):

Eu não sei se é muito ético os candidatos fazerem aqui perguntas, mas cá vai:

> Porque é que você se candidatou a moderador?

Comment: Sim, é ético. Se o pessoal não gostar, tem o botão de downvote. Se for uma pergunta boa, tem o botão de upvote. Além disso, os próprios candidatos fazerem perguntas é algo que estimula o debate entre eles, então é saudável. E caso algum candidato abuse disso ao postar uma pergunta de caráter eleitoreiro, duvidoso ou tendencioso, todo mundo vai socar o dedo no botão do down e ele vai perder uns votos, então nem precisa se preocupar com esse problema.

Answer (score 6):

Reaproveitando [uma das minhas perguntas do ano passado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3910/132):

**Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?**

Acho essa pergunta pertinente porque já vi casos de perguntas que embora fossem de má qualidade, acabam sendo fechadas ou recebendo votos contrários sem maiores explicações para quem fez a pergunta, e o autor da pergunta fica sem orientação. Também acho importante frisar que muitas vezes os novos usuários não conseguem entender o texto dos comentários enlatados, seja porque ele é genérico e impessoal demais ou porque ele parece estar fora do contexto.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Estava a ler a [lista de perguntas de 2015](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3900/129) e encontrei esta que re-utilizo aqui:</sub>

Hoje em dia, eu tenho lido/visto em vários locais o uso da expressão **soft skills**. 
*"soft skills pode ser definido como um conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas"*

 Diante disso, qual/quais *soft skills* você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?

Answer (score 3):

Reaproveitando [uma das minhas perguntas do ano passado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3906/132):

**Qual é o conjunto de tags que você visita com mais frequência e quais os tipos de perguntas que você está mais propenso e capacitado a responder?**

Acho que esta pergunta é importante porque acho que os moderadores tem que ter um conhecimento ao menos razoável sobre aquilo que eles moderam, de forma a poder julgar o que é on-topic ou off-topic, o que é uma pergunta duplicada ou apenas parecida e também para saber como os moderadores podem ajudar a comunidade também como usuários normais. Além disso, uma vez que o escopo do SOpt é muito abrangente e diversificado e não dá para uma única pessoa ter conhecimento razoável sobre tudo, é importante que tenhamos moderadores com conhecimentos diversificados na área de tecnologia e programação.

Answer (score 3):

Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?