# Eleições para Moderador 2018 - Coleção de Perguntas

Tags: debate, eleição

O Stack Overflow em Português tem uma eleição agendada para [a próxima semana, 8 de Outubro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/3).

Como parte da eleição, temos uma sessão de perguntas e respostas com os candidatos. É a oportunidade da comunidade de entender melhor como os candidatos pensam a respeito da moderação do site. A participação é voluntária.

Ao contrário das últimas iterações, a coleta de perguntas e respostas será feita com uma semana de avanço das eleições propriamente ditas. Isto permitirá aos utilizadores algum tempo extra para avaliarem a sua decisão de se nomearem, bem como providenciar respostas ao questionário durante a fase de nomeações.

> **O objetivo deste post era coletar as perguntas que fariam parte do nosso questionário para os candidatos. Você pode acompanhar as respostas [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7372/elei%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-moderador-2018-question%C3%A1rio).**

Como funciona:

- Essa pergunta ficará aberta até o fim da fase de nomeações (até 08/10/2018 às 20:00:00Z UTC; 17:00 Brasília; 21:00 Lisboa) para que vocês enviem suas perguntas aos candidatos. Basta responder esse post com a sua pergunta. Mas apenas *uma pergunta por post!*
- Nós, da Equipe de Comunidades, também temos algumas genéricas para os candidatos de todas as eleições. Dentre essas, as duas primeiras vão ser incluídas na lista final. O resto só será utilizado se a comunidade não enviar um número suficiente de perguntas. Nossas perguntas serão colocadas todas em uma resposta a esse post.
- Aproveitem essa oportunidade para perguntar sobre os temas que te interessam sobre a moderação e os desafios enfrentados pela comunidade.
- Ao final dessa fase, serão escolhidas **no máximo 8 entre as peguntas mais votadas aqui**, que serão utilizadas junto das outras 2 perguntas padrão. Nos reservamos o direito editorial sobre as perguntas enviadas pela comunidade, e podemos não escolher perguntas que julgarmos irrelevantes à eleição. Dito isso, se alguma pergunta apresentar problemas, nós vamos falar a respeito nos comentários.
- Depois que as perguntas forem escolhidas, elas serão listadas em um novo tópico no Meta, com o questionário para os candidatos. Serão 10 perguntas no total.
- Essa não é a única oportunidade que a comunidade tem de conhecer melhor os candidatos. Vocês podem, por exemplo, organizar debates públicos no chat da eleição ou conversar mais a fundo sobre os temas discutidos no questionário.
- Acredito que ainda podemos fazer um bom trabalho com as perguntas de vocês. Os candidatos terão toda a fase final da eleição para elaborar suas respostas. Como inspiração, podem dar uma olhada nas [perguntas de 2015](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3886/elei%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-moderador-2015-cole%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-perguntas) e [2016](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5201/elei%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-moderador-2016-cole%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-perguntas).

Caso tenham mais perguntas, ou sugestões, sobre como funciona o questionário, basta comentar aqui.

Comment: "New contributor" with diamond? lol

Answer (score 20):

É comum nos depararmos com perguntas mal-elaboradas aqui no site (por preguiça ou mesmo por falta de experiência dos usuários).

Essas perguntas, ou pelo menos a maioria delas, é redigida por usuários novatos e afetam diretamente o comportamento dos usuários mais veteranos e dedicados, em alguns casos tornando eles intolerantes ou apenas indiferentes.

Como moderador, gostaria de saber qual é sua visão do problema citado, como pretende "esfriar" e motivar esses usuários?

Answer (score 18):

> Você entende a cultura da comunidade e o que realmente a tornou grande ou acredita simplesmente que moderador é um suporte técnico para perguntas com algumas funções a mais?

Answer (score 14):

Moderar não é simples e toma muito mais tempo do que as pessoas imaginam. E é bem burocrático. Falo disto com mais detalhes em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7355/101. Moderar é desagradar quase a todos em algum momento. Ocorre até com os moderadores mais "moderados". O perfil necessário é que tome a responsabilidade para si. Moderar como diamante não é a mesma coisa que moderar comunitariamente. Não podemos errar e depois a pessoa perceber que não dá conta de todo o fardo da moderação.

Você entende isto? Terá tempo para tudo o que diz que fará, manter o que já faz e o que precisa ser feito? A promessa é realista?

A pergunta não é para sim ou não, ela é propositalmente aberta para ver como você entende como a comunidade funciona e o que você fará como diamante que não pode fazer hoje. Não economize pra mostrar pra gente como vê isto.

Answer (score 13):

Este é um conjunto de perguntas genéricas, que aparecem constantemente em todas as eleições na rede. Conforme dito acima, as duas primeiras perguntas sempre fazem parte do questionário final. As outras serão utilizadas caso não tenhamos perguntas suficientes vindas da comunidade.
É permitido enviar uma dessas perguntas como sua, para ser votada pela comunidade, caso você deseje que ela faça parte do questionário final.

- Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?
- Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

---

- Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?
- Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas, respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?
- De que maneiras você acredita que pode ajudar o site, como moderador, que não seriam possíveis com os privilégios de 10 ou 20 mil?

Answer (score 13):

Como você acredita que deve ser a imparcialidade de um moderador na hora de lidar com um amigo ou com um membro de alta pontuação dentro da comunidade? E como lidaria com um membro com mais experiência que você no site?

Answer (score 12):

É comum vermos muitos casos de problemas no site, parece que estamos enxugando gelo. E temos outros afazeres. Tudo isto pode ir afastando um moderador da sua atividade para que foi eleito. Caso isto ocorra e sua "produtividade" no site caia muito, você acha que estará cumprindo o que se propôs fazer? E o que fará a respeito? Mesmo que considere que não acontecerá com você faça um exercício da hipótese.

Comment: Isso é importante, em diferentes medidas aconteceu com todos os atuais moderadores – talvez até você.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, é experiência própria.

Answer (score 11):

Além da sua participação normal no site, como você pretende gerenciar seu tempo com as atividades de moderação? Caso tenha alguma ocupação extra-site e já investe parte do seu tempo participando da comunidade, como lidará com o fato de, provavelmente, ter que abrir mão de ganhar reputação perguntando/respondendo para moderar?

São duas perguntas, mas acho que estão intrinsecamente relacionadas, podendo ser considerada apenas uma. Baseada na pergunta do [utluiz♦](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5204/5878).

Answer (score 9):

Reaproveitando uma [pergunta minha da eleição de 2016](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5209/132):

> Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?

Answer (score 8):

Ser moderador também é ser um alvo preferencial de muitos usuários problemáticos. Inclusive, há usuários problemáticos com alta reputação. Como você lidaria com ataques de outros usuários que envolvam acusações e provocações contra você nos mais diversos cenários onde isso certamente vai acontecer se você for eleito?

Answer (score 8):

Talvez você já seja um ótimo usuário e moderador comunitário. Por que você precisa dos poderes de moderador ♦? O que poderá fazer que já não faz ou pode fazer hoje? Por que agregará a equipe atual?

Answer (score 6):

Como você acha que deve agir um moderador caso tenha que lidar, por algum motivo, com uma pergunta que tenha uma resposta dele mesmo, ou até mesmo que a pergunta seja dele mesmo?

Por exemplo, a comunidade fecha uma pergunta, mas o moderador acha que ela tem potencial e reabre a pergunta. Sendo que tem uma resposta desse moderador nessa pergunta.

Answer (score 5):

Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores? Como atuará como tal? Não cabe aqui o que já faz ou faria como usuário ou moderador comunitário, a eleição é para lhe dar um diamante. Seja o mais completo e preciso que puder.

Comment: Acho que já é duplicata da pergunta genérica: Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?
Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas, respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?

Comment: São exemplos, e se nós queremos que um delas entre ela precisa ser votada.

Comment: Entendi. "É permitido enviar uma dessas perguntas como sua, para ser votada pela comunidade, caso você deseje que ela faça parte do questionário final."

Comment: Uma das de exemplo sim, das padrões não.

Answer (score -3):

Você já foi moderador ou possui alguma experiência similar? Como foi e por que esta experiência te ajudará no SOpt?

Answer (score -3):

É comum novos usuários ou usuários inexperientes participarem de forma incorreta no site, seja postando perguntas ou respostas de má qualidade, ou usando as ferramentas de avaliações de forma ruim.

Muitos desses usuários, pela inexperiência, criam contas, participam pouco e *somem* diante de uma falta de receptividade positiva e construtiva.

Como moderador, como você pretende auxiliar esses usuários a se engajarem ao site evitando evasão e favorecer para que esses usuários se tornem bons usuários e usuários ativos?

Answer (score -4):

O moderador tem uma posição de liderança perante a comunidade e como tal deve dar bons exemplos, como se espera de tal o **SOPT**. Como moderador, como pretende exercer essa liderança e dar bons exemplos àqueles usuários que você não tem simpatia?

Ter paciência, saber ouvir, ser justo, analisar os fatos de forma imparcial (conciliado com a devida firmeza) são atribuições que se espera de um moderador. Muitas vezes essas coisas não são fáceis, mas são imposições do cargo. Você está disposto a isso ou vai agir por "paixão cega"?