# Eleições para Moderador 2020 - Coleta de Perguntas

Tags: debate, eleição

O Stack Overflow em Português tem uma eleição agendada para [a próxima semana, 28 de Setembro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/4).

Como parte da eleição, temos uma sessão de perguntas e respostas com os candidatos. É a oportunidade da comunidade de entender melhor como os candidatos pensam a respeito da moderação do site. A participação é voluntária.

Ao contrário das últimas iterações, a coleta de perguntas e respostas será feita com uma semana de avanço das eleições propriamente ditas. Isto permitirá aos utilizadores algum tempo extra para avaliarem a sua decisão de se nomearem, bem como providenciar respostas ao questionário durante a fase de nomeações.

Como funciona:

- Essa pergunta ficará aberta até o início da fase de nomeações (até 28/09/2020 às 20:00:00Z UTC; 17:00 Brasília; 21:00 Lisboa) para que vocês enviem suas perguntas aos candidatos. Basta responder esse post com a sua pergunta. Mas apenas *uma pergunta por post!*
- Nós, da Equipe de Comunidades, também temos algumas genéricas para os candidatos de todas as eleições. Dentre essas, as duas primeiras vão ser incluídas na lista final. O resto só será utilizado se a comunidade não enviar um número suficiente de perguntas. Nossas perguntas serão colocadas todas em uma resposta a esse post.
- Aproveitem essa oportunidade para perguntar sobre os temas que te interessam sobre a moderação e os desafios enfrentados pela comunidade.
- Ao final dessa fase, serão escolhidas **no máximo 8 entre as peguntas mais votadas aqui**, que serão utilizadas junto das outras 2 perguntas padrão. Nos reservamos o direito editorial sobre as perguntas enviadas pela comunidade, e podemos não escolher perguntas que julgarmos irrelevantes à eleição. Dito isso, se alguma pergunta apresentar problemas, nós vamos falar a respeito nos comentários.
- Depois que as perguntas forem escolhidas, elas serão listadas em um novo tópico no Meta, com o questionário para os candidatos. Serão 10 perguntas no total.
- Essa não é a única oportunidade que a comunidade tem de conhecer melhor os candidatos. Vocês podem, por exemplo, organizar debates públicos no chat da eleição ou conversar mais a fundo sobre os temas discutidos no questionário.
- Acredito que ainda podemos fazer um bom trabalho com as perguntas de vocês. Os candidatos terão toda a fase final da eleição para elaborar suas respostas. Como inspiração, podem dar uma olhada nas [perguntas de 2015](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3886/elei%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-moderador-2015-cole%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-perguntas), [2016](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5201/elei%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-moderador-2016-cole%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-perguntas) e [2018](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7330/144721).

Caso tenham mais perguntas, ou sugestões, sobre como funciona o questionário, basta comentar aqui.

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113591/discussion-on-question-by-cesar-m-eleicoes-para-moderador-2020-coleta-de-pergu) para não tirar o foco da coleta de perguntas.

Answer (score 20):

Considerando que os votos são - ou pelo menos já foram - a [segunda coisa mais importante do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/112052) (a primeira são as perguntas e respostas), como você vê o fato de que [as pessoas hoje estão votando menos que antigamente](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1294799/quantidade-de-votos-por-mes#graph)?

[image: votos por mês SOpt]

Se você concorda que isso é um problema, qual seria a solução?

Mas se você acha que isso não é um problema, por favor explique porquê.

---

Apenas a título de comparação, [o mesmo gráfico com os votos do SOen](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1297747/votes-per-month#graph).

[image: votos por mês SOen]

---

Só pra deixar claro que meu questionamento é sobre a quantidade total de votos estar diminuindo. O fato de ter mais negativos que positivos é um detalhe (claro que isso também pode ser abordado, mas o ponto principal é que as pessoas de forma geral estão votando menos, e quero saber o que os candidatos pensam sobre isso).

Comment: Gráfico interessante, não sabia disso. Enquanto upvotes diminuem, downvotes aumentam e estamos próximos da primeira inversão...

Comment: -1 ? Quem negativou poderia ao menos justificar o motivo de discordar dessa pergunta para os futuros candidatos?

Answer (score 17):

Sendo eleito moderador diamante, como atuará em relação a diversidade de pensamento considerando essas questões:

- A SE não ouve a comunidade ou moderadores, você vai brigar com eles? Ou concorda com tudo o que eles fazem?
- Outros moderadores já tem uma atuação conhecida. O que fará quando você pensar diferente? Se não conseguir convencer os demais que está certo, partirá para o conflito? Ou fará o que bem entender? Ou aceitará que sem consenso não pode atuar como quer?
- Vai ouvir a comunidade ou fazer o que achar melhor unilateralmente? E quem é a comunidade para você? São os usuários ativos?

Tente explicar o melhor que puder essa questão para conhecemos o que realmente importa, porque é só isso que está em jogo.

Comment: Esta é uma das perguntas padrões da SE com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 13):

No final de 2019, a SE tomou atitudes e posturas que desagradaram grande parte de seus usuários, inclusive levando a renúncia em massa de diversos moderadores de diversos sites da rede. Qual é a sua postura quanto a esses eventos? Conhecendo esses eventos, como você pretende pautar seu relacionamento com a SE?

Answer (score 12):

Uma reclamação frequente e antiga aqui no site é a falta de feedback ao OP em perguntas que tem problemas e são fechadas com pouco ou nenhum comentário destinado ao OP. Por outro lado, do ponto de vista de quem fecha as perguntas, ficar dando feedback inúmeras vezes para então ser atacado ou ser arrastado para debates intermináveis e improdutivos que dificilmente mudarão algo é uma atividade extremamente desgastante e desmotivadora. Qual é a sua opinião sobre isso? O que você fará quanto a isso?

Answer (score 10):

"Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?"

Answer (score 9):

Você entende a diferença de uma "pergunta de  helpdesk" (pergunta que basicamente só serve para o autor) para uma pergunta legitima e útil para comunidade (que agrega ao repositório de conhecimento, [objetivo do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/3635))? Se sim, explique seu ponto de vista.

Comment: -2 ? Quem negativou poderia ao menos justificar o motivo de discordar dessa pergunta para os futuros candidatos?

Comment: O site é visto como uma ferramenta de suporte no geral, dificilmente vai ter perguntas que são feitas pensando nas pessoas de forma geral, acredito que isso esta ficando mais frequente ainda, esse tipo de perguntas pode levar a muitos problemas como mais dificuldade em encontrar soluções ou um material bom e canônico para usar como fonte de aprendizagem.

Comment: @gato creio que não compreendi, a intenção é explicar o pq a pergunta feita aqui não é boa ou esta respondendo ao que eu perguntei?

Comment: Foi um desabafo xD

Comment: Uma pregunta `helpdesk` é aquela que foi elaborada de forma específica para apenas uma só situação. Pergunta esta, que só vai servir para resolver uma só questão do autor da pergunta. Já a pergunta `legítima e útil`, é aquela que visa resolver uma questão de forma bem abrangente. Este segundo tipo de pergunta - quando se tem uma boa resposta - será bem mais visitada e aceita pela comunidade.

Comment: @Solkarped eu to achando, que o pessoal não entendeu o propósito de coletar perguntas, não estamos buscando respostas, essas perguntas são para o futuro, para os candidatos, elas devem ser respondidas na época da eleição.

Comment: cc @gato, o mesmo dito no comentário anterior

Answer (score 9):

Você faria algo de diferente com relação a forma de comunicação da moderação atual com os demais usuários da comunidade?

Answer (score 9):

O grande problema do site é a falta de moderação comunitária. Não há falta de moderação diamante, então de que maneiras você acredita que pode ajudar o site, como moderador, que não seriam possíveis com os privilégios de 10 ou 20 mil? Acha que pode acontecer o contrário e ajudar menos do que ajuda agora?

Comment: Esta é uma das perguntas padrões da SE com um texto adicional.

Answer (score 7):

Este é um conjunto de perguntas genéricas, que aparecem constantemente em todas as eleições na rede. Conforme dito acima, as duas primeiras perguntas sempre fazem parte do questionário final. As outras serão utilizadas caso não tenhamos perguntas suficientes vindas da comunidade.
É permitido enviar uma dessas perguntas como sua, para ser votada pela comunidade, caso você deseje que ela faça parte do questionário final.

- Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?
- Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

---

- Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?
- Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas, respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?
- De que maneiras você acredita que pode ajudar o site, como moderador, que não seriam possíveis com os privilégios de 10 ou 20 mil?

Answer (score 7):

Como usuário até o momento, compreende que a comunidade tem uma identidade própria e visa certos meios de obter perguntas mais claras e voltadas ao máximo para o escopo e utilidade como por exemplo o [Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/3635) e o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/3635)? Se compreende, explique seu ponto de vista sobre isso.

Comment: -1 ? Quem negativou poderia ao menos justificar o motivo de discordar dessa pergunta para os futuros candidatos?

Comment: Olha, não fui eu que dei negativo (e nem positivo). Mas essa pergunta me parece ser algo que bastaria o candidato responder "*sim, entendo isso e concordo*" e pronto estará respondido, mas isso não servirá para contrastar ou comparar as diferentes opiniões e visões dos diferentes candidatos, pois somente um candidato muito fora dos eixos daria uma resposta diferente do esperado.

Comment: @VictorStafusa faz sentido

Answer (score 7):

Em sua opinião, o que o(a) moderador(a) **não** deveria fazer? Por quê?

Answer (score 7):

Durante a [fase de candidatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election?tab=nomination), muitos candidatos deram a entender (alguns inclusive deixando mais claro que outros) que estavam esperando se tornar moderadores para só depois começar a fazer as atividades de moderação comunitária (fechar, votar, filas de análise, comentários, etc).

Muitos deles já tinham pontuação suficiente para fazer algumas dessas atividades, mas os seus históricos até então mostravam que eles haviam usado pouco - ou nunca haviam usado - tais ferramentas (muitos sequer tinham participado do Meta, por exemplo).

Se você se enquadra no caso acima, por que acha que só depois de se tornar um moderador é que passará a fazer essas coisas, sendo que já poderia estar fazendo?

E se você não se enquadra no caso acima, como conscientizar os usuários para que eles usem mais as ferramentas de moderação comunitária? Como mudar essa ideia, que muitos têm, de que só moderadores podem fazer tais atividades?

Answer (score 6):

Acredita que o papel do moderador não é ajudar em dúvidas, mas sim em cuidar de problemas mais graves da comunidade? Explique o seu ponto de vista.

Comment: Fora essa pergunta, que eu votei a favor, as demais eu votei contra, não por acahar elas ruins ou sem sentido (na verdade até acho interessante o debate delas em posts separados aqui no meta), apenas menos relevante considerando que o intuito é avaliar os possíveis futuros moderadores

Comment: @Costamilam compreendo e respeito, mas visando minhas experiências no site e meu entendimento, fora minha atuação em fechamentos essa perguntas que formulei são estratégicas para obter o nivel de qualificação e o quanto o candidato estará alinhado, mesmo que a maioria não entenda o que essas perguntas signifiquem.

Answer (score 3):

- Como você pretende orientar os novos membros do SOpt? Você orienta eles mesmo não sendo um moderador diamante ♦?

Comment: E eu ainda acrescentaria "Como isso não precisa do diamante, você o fazia como usuário normal? Porque?" - Um dos princípios da rede é que todos são moderadores, os pontos vão dando mais e mais poderes. O diamante `♦` indicador de mod é para uso em último caso. De curiosidade: se eu como mod fechar uma duplicata de PHP, vai ser fechada pela tag de ouro como usuário normal, e não com o "diamante" (que é um poder que eu ja tinha sem o diamante e usava - o diamante foi um complemento pra moderação que eu já fazia sem)

Comment: @Bacco, me desculpe não entendi seu comentario

Comment: Basicamente quis dizer que acho interessante saber como a pessoa pretende orientar, mas para ser moderador é natural que a pessoa já faça isso como usuário. É uma coisa comum na nossa rede que o moderador eleito já venha sendo moderador comunitário no dia a dia, então eu perguntaria se a pessoa já está fazendo isso. Quem sonha que vai começar o trabalho só quando eleito geralmente não tem noção do que é o site (e eu particularmente considero voto jogado fora).

Comment: Ataa, ok, irei editar a pergunta! :)

Answer (score 3):

Que importância dá à actividade de moderação que um candidato teve enquanto usuário?
Porquê?

Answer (score 3):

Quanto tempo você pretende investir na moderação da comunidade? Isso será suficiente para suprir as necessidades atuais da moderação? E o que fará caso apareça alguma ocupação fora do site que irá ocupar esse tempo que havia dedicado?

Answer (score 3):

De [acordo com a comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8143/5878) muita coisa poderia ser diferente do que é hoje. Qual será a sua posição como moderador quanto a isso?

Comment: Não sei se é uma pergunta muito útil. Esse link tem várias ideias legais, mas é apenas um exercício de sonho e imaginação. Nesse aspecto, a opinião de um candidato a moderador tem o mesmo peso da de qualquer outro usuário: zero!

Answer (score 3):

Eu por exemplo, como muitos outros, sou um usuário que era muito ativo no passado, mas que agora quase nem mais acesso o site. Este site se tornou um lugar extremamente desmotivador e tentativas de tornar a situação um pouco melhor são recebidas com ceticismo e negatividade que também desmotivam quem tenta por um ou dois dias fazer algo*. Os atuais moderadores reclamam abertamente da comunidade e não escondem seu descontentamento, e a SE também não ajuda. A comunidade tem uma forte divisão entre novatos e veteranos, com um número cada vez menor de novatos que amadurecem e eventualmente tornam-se a nova geração de veteranos e uma proporção cada vez maior de novatos que abandonam o site.

Sabendo que você terá grandes limitações como moderador e sabendo que não adianta querer ser o salvador da pátria, o que você pretende fazer para melhorar essa situação? O que você acha que dá para você fazer para melhorar o ânimo e a motivação aqui na comunidade?

---

`*` - E falo isso de experiência própria, pois quebrei a cara na minha última tentativa de melhorar e o otimismo durou pouco, o que me levou a me desmotivar ainda mais.

Comment: *falo isso de experiência própria, pois quebrei a cara na minha última tentativa de melhorar e o otimismo durou pouco*, apenas por curiosidade, foi uma iniciativa com post no Meta ou por comentários? Se tiver algum link, aceito-o. Queria saber mais sobre (conheço pouco do "passado" do SOpt)

Comment: @RafaelTavares Aqui - https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8295/132 - Mas considero o resultado final extremamente decepcionante. Inclusive, fui bastante atacado no decorrer desse processo e rapidamente me desmotivei com isso, o que só serviu para que depois dissessem que eu sumi e fui embora (e fui mesmo, tamanha a desmotivação).

Comment: "Os atuais moderadores reclamam abertamente da comunidade" - Por outros não posso falar, mas da minha parte, o que tem problema é o montão de gente que não quer integrar a comunidade. Considero comunidade quem está presente (ou esteve) e durante este tempo ajuda a formar o repositório de conhecimento (desde postando conteúdo de qualidade a ajudando novos usuários a entenderem a proposta). Essa é a parte que eu não reclamo, é o que me mantém aqui ainda, a comunidade. Eu reclamo abertamente é do resto, que vem procurar solução pra problema individual e não liga a mínima mesmo orrientado.

Answer (score 2):

Você compreende configurações de servidor, infra, docker como sendo escopo de um site de programação ou não? Se acredita que faz parte do escopo e que devemos abordar isso no site explique sua motivação e ponto de vista sobre o assunto.

Comment: -1 ? Quem negativou poderia ao menos justificar o motivo de discordar dessa pergunta para os futuros candidatos?

Comment: Eu deixei meu -1 porque, ao meu ver, a pergunta assim bem específica sobre infra eu não vejo como poderia mudar o voto da pessoa para moderador ou não, dado que isso nem seria uma decisão dela. Porém, todavia, entretanto, uma versão mais genérica desta pergunta poderia ser útil, algo como "é bastante comum na comunidade a discussão sobre o que é ou não é escopo, você como moderador, o que fará a respeito? como lidará com esse tipo de discussão?" ou algo assim.

Answer (score 2):

Em sua opinião, por que os moderadores deveriam ou não receber pelo seu trabalho aqui no site?

Comment: Menos um? Me fala ai o por que você considera irrelevante opinião dum candidato a moderador sobre dispor ou não gratuitamente parte do seu tempo de vida sendo engrenagem de uma estrutura comercial que obtém lucros justamente por conta de sua atividade?

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas acho que o motivo (só estou presumindo) é que isso já é algo bem definido pela empresa SO em todos sites da rede SE, não temos nem como discutir, pois somos um site pequeno esquecidos pela SO e se isso não é debate no Metão, dificilmente será um debate que "irá para frente" aqui. Mas acho compreendo a motivação da pergunta e realmente seria bom termos um CM (funcionário da empresa SO) que atua-se aqui no site.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, entendi o seu ponto de vista, o aceito e compartilho dele. Mas no momento eu não estou tão interessado no debate e nem nas minhas próprias opiniões eu realmente quero conhecer o pensamento de quem vou votar.

Comment: Compreendo e concordo totalmente, não vale a pena debater, por isso no máximo só tentei especular mesmo o motivo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu quero avaliar primeiro a pessoa para então julgar a proposta de trabalho. Eu entendo o funcionamento da SE e sei que a postura não irá se alterar porém gostaria de testar o julgamento moral dos candidatos e imaginei que uma situação que fugisse ao controle do candidato fornecesse um balizamento para assim distinguir o indivíduo do arquétipo.

Comment: Eu dei meu -1 porque eu particularmente não vejo essa pergunta como útil que deveria entrar na listagem de perguntas selecionadas. Tem muitas outras melhores que as respostas dos candidatos dirão muito mais sobre como ele pretende atuar na comunidade do que apenas saber se na visão dele deveria ser remunerado ou não. Mas, por outro lado, essa pergunta poderia ser muito bem enviada como comentário aos candidatos.

Comment: @Woss. Entendi e agradeço a orientação. Obrigado por compartilhar sua opinião.

Answer (score 1):

Como moderador, **você integrará um time** que hoje é composto por 6 pessoas, sendo eles eleitos em 2015, 2016 e 2018. Dito isso, gostaria de saber:

- Qual é a sua relação com os moderadores atuais?
- Quais são os pontos positivos da moderação atual que você julga importante manter?
- Quais são os pontos negativos da moderação atual que você julga importante NÃO manter? O que pretende fazer em relação a isso?
- Quais são os pontos que você julga que a moderação atual deixa de fazer? O que pretende fazer em relação a isso?

---

*Sim, são várias perguntas, mas todas sobre o mesmo ponto, que poderia ser facilmente reescrita em forma de uma pergunta única, porém os tópicos ajudarão na leitura e entendimento. Ainda é basicamente uma versão mais abrangente [desta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8418/5878) e [desta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8409/5878)*

Comment: Essa *"Qual é a sua relação com os moderadores atuais?"* merece ser uma pergunta exclusiva.

Comment: @AugustoVasques algo nesse sentido? https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8416/101

Comment: @Maniero, sim. Inclusive já havia deixado um up-vote.

Comment: Woss, vou plagiar sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você conhece o termo [preguiçoso](https://www.google.com/search?q=pregui%C3%A7oso&oq=pregui%C3%A7oso&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.3720j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Analisando seus sumários de participações no [Satck Overflow em Português META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) e [Satck Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) mostre claramente que você não é apenas um preguiçoso buscando uma posição mais confortável dentro do site e que sim, na verdade você é um membro valoroso, contributivo e participativo para comunidade Stack Overflow em Português e mostre com números os porquês de você ser valioso ao ponto de receber um diamante?

Comment: Não acredito que você me deu um negativo. Mas independente do seu voto essa pergunta ainda pode ser lida e fará com que olhem seus próprios perfis antes de criarem futuras candidaturas do bicho preguiça.