# Eleições para Moderador 2020 - Questionário

Tags: debate, eleição

Essa é a sessão de perguntas e respostas para os candidatos à moderador do Stack Overflow em Português. As perguntas enviadas [na pergunta anterior](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8400/elei%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-moderador-2020-coleta-de-perguntas) estão listadas aqui, para que os candidatos possam respondê-las.

Nem todas as perguntas foram compiladas — como denotado anteriormente, só selecionámos as perguntas enviadas pela comunidade com mais votos, para além do conjunto por defeito da nossa parte, para um total de 10 perguntas.

Os candidatos devem responder esse post, listando cada pergunta do questionário e a sua resposta. Para ajudar, as perguntas estão pré-formatadas como citações e com espaço entre elas, para sua resposta. Basta copiar tudo [depois da linha divisória](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/36f9e9eb-883d-4f53-8377-762c3a2a84d0/view-source). Lembrem-se também de colocar seu nome no **topo** do seu post, para que todo mundo possa saber quem é *antes* de ler tudo que você escreveu.

Depois que todos responderem, esse tópico será um registro das ideias e propostas de cada candidato e vai aparecer na perfil de cada um na página da eleição.

Boa sorte!

**Ah, e quando tiveres completado a tua resposta, por favor fornece um link para a mesma depois desta porção de texto, antes do conjunto de três travessões. Por favor deixa a lista de links de acordo com a ordem em que as respostas foram apresentadas.**

Para poupar no scroll, aqui estão os links para as respostas de cada candidato (pela ordem em que foram apresentadas):

- [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8452/)
- [Rebeca Nonato](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8454/)
- [Wallace Maxters](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8456)

---

> 1. Considerando que os votos são - ou pelo menos já foram - a [segunda coisa mais importante do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/112052) (a primeira são as perguntas e respostas), como você vê o fato de que [as pessoas hoje estão votando menos que antigamente](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1294799/quantidade-de-votos-por-mes#graph)? Se você concorda que isso é um problema, qual seria a solução? Mas se você acha que isso não é um problema, por favor explique porquê.
>    Só pra deixar claro que meu questionamento é sobre a quantidade total de votos estar diminuindo. O fato de ter mais negativos que positivos é um detalhe (claro que isso também pode ser abordado, mas o ponto principal é que as pessoas de forma geral estão votando menos, e quero saber o que os candidatos pensam sobre isso).

> 2. Sendo eleito moderador diamante, como atuará em relação a diversidade de pensamento considerando essas questões:
>
> - A SE não ouve a comunidade ou moderadores, você vai brigar com eles? Ou concorda com tudo o que eles fazem?
> - Outros moderadores já tem uma atuação conhecida. O que fará quando você pensar diferente? Se não conseguir convencer os demais que está certo, partirá para o conflito? Ou fará o que bem entender? Ou aceitará que sem consenso não pode atuar como quer?
> - Vai ouvir a comunidade ou fazer o que achar melhor unilateralmente? E quem é a comunidade para você? São os usuários ativos?
>
> Tente explicar o melhor que puder essa questão para conhecemos o que realmente importa, porque é só isso que está em jogo.

> 3. No final de 2019, a SE tomou atitudes e posturas que desagradaram grande parte de seus usuários, inclusive levando a renúncia em massa de diversos moderadores de diversos sites da rede. Qual é a sua postura quanto a esses eventos? Conhecendo esses eventos, como você pretende pautar seu relacionamento com a SE?

> 4. Uma reclamação frequente e antiga aqui no site é a falta de feedback ao OP em perguntas que tem problemas e são fechadas com pouco ou nenhum comentário destinado ao OP. Por outro lado, do ponto de vista de quem fecha as perguntas, ficar dando feedback inúmeras vezes para então ser atacado ou ser arrastado para debates intermináveis e improdutivos que dificilmente mudarão algo é uma atividade extremamente desgastante e desmotivadora. Qual é a sua opinião sobre isso? O que você fará quanto a isso?

> 5. "Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?"

> 6. Você faria algo de diferente com relação a forma de comunicação da moderação atual com os demais usuários da comunidade?

> 7. O grande problema do site é a falta de moderação comunitária. Não há falta de moderação diamante, então de que maneiras você acredita que pode ajudar o site, como moderador, que não seriam possíveis com os privilégios de 10 ou 20 mil? Acha que pode acontecer o contrário e ajudar menos do que ajuda agora?

> 8. Você entende a diferença de uma "pergunta de helpdesk" (pergunta que basicamente só serve para o autor) para uma pergunta legitima e útil para comunidade (que agrega ao repositório de conhecimento, objetivo do site)? Se sim, explique seu ponto de vista.

> 9. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

> 10. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Comment: Será que algum candidato se preocupará em responder o questionário?

Comment: Amanhã terminam as eleições. É possível presumir que os candidatos cujo não apresentaram as respostas a esse questionário desistiram?

Comment: @AugustoVasques infelizmente não é :D Alguns nem conseguem entender o processo que entraram. Também podem ter desistido e não perceberam que podem oficializar isso. Tem candidato que não acessa o site há vários dias. Exceto por dois, nunca tinham participado do meta para ajudar, um deles fez uma pergunta (duplicada). BTW, obrigado pelo excelente trabalho feito nas eleições.

Answer (score 12):

### Wallace Maxters

> 1. Considerando que os votos são - ou pelo menos já foram - a [segunda coisa mais importante do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/112052) (a primeira são as perguntas e respostas), como você vê o fato de que [as pessoas hoje estão votando menos que antigamente](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1294799/quantidade-de-votos-por-mes#graph)? Se você concorda que isso é um problema, qual seria a solução? Mas se você acha que isso não é um problema, por favor explique porquê.
>    Só pra deixar claro que meu questionamento é sobre a quantidade total de votos estar diminuindo. O fato de ter mais negativos que positivos é um detalhe (claro que isso também pode ser abordado, mas o ponto principal é que as pessoas de forma geral estão votando menos, e quero saber o que os candidatos pensam sobre isso).

Creio que a falta de votos tem a ver com a qualidade do conteúdo, e esse é o problema verdadeiro. Independente dos votos diminuirem, a proporção de negativos aumentou muito. Eu sou um dos que preza pela qualidade em perguntas e respostas, preferindo evitar as perguntas que têm claramente o objetivo apenas de sanar a própria dúvida do usuário ao invés de ajudar a comunidade. Eu acredito que a comunidade (a que realmente preza pelo site) já tenha boas diretrizes de como se formar boas perguntas e é comum que o usuário melhore a qualidade do conteúdo produzido a medida que se envolva na comunidade. A melhor solução para isso é orientar os usuários a seguir o caminho melhor para formulação de perguntas e respostas, e valorizar o bom conteúdo.

> 2. Sendo eleito moderador diamante, como atuará em relação a diversidade de pensamento considerando essas questões:
>
> - A SE não ouve a comunidade ou moderadores, você vai brigar com eles? Ou concorda com tudo o que eles fazem?

Eu não concordo com todas as decisões da SE, mas "brigar" com a empresa, que é dona do site, não faz sentido.
Os próprios usuários podem pensar diferente em diversos assuntos e, mesmo assim, com respeito, é possível conviver harmoniosamente; não tem porque ser diferente com a empresa.
O Meta existe para debatermos e propôr o funcionamento do site, e nós podemos apresentar as idéias, ficando ao encargo da empresa aceitar ou não as ideias e proposições

> - Outros moderadores já tem uma atuação conhecida. O que fará quando você pensar diferente? Se não conseguir convencer os demais que está certo, partirá para o conflito? Ou fará o que bem entender? Ou aceitará que sem consenso não pode atuar como quer?

É uma situação parecida a anterior: conviver com divergências de opiniões, e eu sempre fiz como usuário normal.

Acredito que, como os demais da comunidade, a equipe dos diamantes deve procurar o diálogo nas decisões tomadas. Mas diálogo com a moderação já tenho hoje como usuário, não tem porque mudar com o diamante.

> - Vai ouvir a comunidade ou fazer o que achar melhor unilateralmente? E quem é a comunidade para você? São os usuários ativos?
>   Tente explicar o melhor que puder essa questão para conhecemos o que realmente importa, porque é só isso que está em jogo.

Uma decisão unilateral só deve ser tomada em último caso, quando há algum problema que pode piorar, caso o mesmo seja ignorado.
As pessoas às vezes esquecem que praticamente tudo no site é reversível pela própria comunidade, caso haja erro de moderação. Todo o sistema foi criado com esse propósito.

> 3. No final de 2019, a SE tomou atitudes e posturas que desagradaram grande parte de seus usuários, inclusive levando a renúncia em massa de diversos moderadores de diversos sites da rede. Qual é a sua postura quanto a esses eventos? Conhecendo esses eventos, como você pretende pautar seu relacionamento com a SE?

Sobre a renúncia, mesmo tendo sido em massa, creio que cada um teve seus critérios e motivos pessoais. Não caberia a mim questionar.
Numa comunidade, sempre existirão várias opiniões e posições divergentes a respeito de diversos assuntos. Independente da postura da SE, o meu objetivo é trabalhar pela proposta do site e pela comunidade.

> 4. Uma reclamação frequente e antiga aqui no site é a falta de feedback ao OP em perguntas que tem problemas e são fechadas com pouco ou nenhum comentário destinado ao OP. Por outro lado, do ponto de vista de quem fecha as perguntas, ficar dando feedback inúmeras vezes para então ser atacado ou ser arrastado para debates intermináveis e improdutivos que dificilmente mudarão algo é uma atividade extremamente desgastante e desmotivadora. Qual é a sua opinião sobre isso? O que você fará quanto a isso?

Estou ciente dos problemas referente a ausência de feedback e fechamentos de perguntas aqui, realmente é um problema antigo.

De fato, há sim essas reclamações, mas nem sempre o motivo destas são justas, pois sempre há aquele usuário que leva a coisa para o lado pessoal, ou acabam não entendendo muito bem o propósito/finalidade do site, criando discussões longas e desgaste.

Creio que, nesses casos, é possível continuar trabalhando essa parte de comunicação, para melhorar a experiência dos usuários, procurando orientar os mais novos a evoluírem dentro da plataforma.

> 5. Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?

Creio que minha opinião seja irrelevante nesse caso. Acredito que todas as diretrizes a serem seguidas estão descritas na [Teoria da moderação](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/). Seguindo essa recomendações, creio que já estou no caminho certo.

> 6. Você faria algo de diferente com relação a forma de comunicação da moderação atual com os demais usuários da comunidade?

Se esse "diferente" seria uma busca melhorias, a resposta é sim. Sempre é importante buscar melhorar a comunicação, principalmente em uma comunidade tão grande como o SOPT. O que não impede de aproveitar a experiência de quem já está fazendo isso antes.

> 7. O grande problema do site é a falta de moderação comunitária. Não há falta de moderação diamante, então de que maneiras você acredita que pode ajudar o site, como moderador, que não seriam possíveis com os privilégios de 10 ou 20 mil? Acha que pode acontecer o contrário e ajudar menos do que ajuda agora?

Creio que o diamante possua mais responsabilidades no que tange a moderação da comunidade, o que leva a necessidade de um zelo maior pela mesma. Mesmo que essa ajuda na moderação comunitária diminuisse como diamante, ainda assim desejo continuar a fazer o meu melhor para o site, comentando, fazendo perguntas, editando e etc.

> 8. Você entende a diferença de uma "pergunta de helpdesk" (pergunta que basicamente só serve para o autor) para uma pergunta legitima e útil para comunidade (que agrega ao repositório de conhecimento, objetivo do site)? Se sim, explique seu ponto de vista.

Entendo sim, inclusive sempre tenho o cuidado de fazer minhas perguntas, colocando palavras e descrevendo o suficiente para o que o problema apresentado se torne facilmente identificável por outros usuários.

Já fiz mais de 1000 perguntas aqui na plataforma e, a maioria dessas, tive a prática de formular de maneira que ajudasse outros membros a sanarem suas dúvidas.

Creio que a "pergunta de helpdesk", se editada e orientada à melhoria, pode se tornar a "pergunta útil para a comunidade", mas também tenho consciência que, em alguns casos, não é possível fazer muita coisa, e o melhor é que ela não fique no site para atrapalhar quem vem buscar conteúdo.

Desde que a pergunta seja "respondível", creio que a "pergunta de helpdesk" ainda sim possa ser proveitosa para a comunidade, mas desde que atenda os requisitos. A mesma ainda poderia ser melhorada, com edições e melhorias, por própria sugestão da comunidade, deixando de ser "helpdesk" e se tornando mais abrangente.

> 9. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Temos que valorizar o usuário e o conteúdo produzido pelo mesmo, porém sempre devemos estar prontos para lidar com situações extremas. Toda situação deve ser muito bem avaliada antes de se tomar uma postura que possa prejudicar qualquer parte. Creio que a melhor forma de lidar com a situação é tentar manter o diálogo e instruir, conforme o [modelo de comportamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) que está destacado na comunidade.

> 10. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

A plataforma já possui uma maneira democrática de tratar esses casos. Creio que isso pode ser mantido tranquilamente, indepentende de estar na moderação ou não. Nesse caso, é melhor ter mais de uma pessoa atuando nessas decisões, para que não prejudique o usuário que fez a pergunta/resposta.

Comment: Na pergunta 3, "*qual é a sua postura quanto a esses eventos?*" - Especificamente, sobre esses eventos, o que você pensa sobre eles? E para ser claro acerca do que são esses eventos, tem a ver com demissão sumária e sem aviso da Monica Cellio, novo código de conduta, comunidade LGBTQI+, marginalização da comunidade pela própria SE, pronomes, supressão de liberdade de expressão, um monte de ações que muitos classificam como mentiras, acusações, hipocrisia, caça as bruxas, etc. e um monte de outras coisas relacionadas. Como candidato, gostaria de saber o que você pensa sobre isso tudo.

Answer (score 10):

### Guilherme Nascimento

> 1. Considerando que os votos são - ou pelo menos já foram - a [segunda coisa mais importante do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/112052) (a primeira são as perguntas e respostas), como você vê o fato de que [as pessoas hoje estão votando menos que antigamente](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1294799/quantidade-de-votos-por-mes#graph)? Se você concorda que isso é um problema, qual seria a solução? Mas se você acha que isso não é um problema, por favor explique porquê.
>    Só pra deixar claro que meu questionamento é sobre a quantidade total de votos estar diminuindo. O fato de ter mais negativos que positivos é um detalhe (claro que isso também pode ser abordado, mas o ponto principal é que as pessoas de forma geral estão votando menos, e quero saber o que os candidatos pensam sobre isso).

No geral a participação de usuários interessados em promover conteúdo de qualidade é que diminuiu, o que refletiu diretamente nos votos, a maioria que vem só pelo suporte personalizado raramente interagem com o resto do site e só na hora que algo realmente vai o ajudar em um momento de sufoco que irão acessar/pesquisar algo no site, creio que seja possível solucionar se todos nós como comunidade divulgarmos o conteúdo quando conveniente e tentar incentivar isso nos que só vem pelo "suporte personalizado", mas não existe solução mágica e nem garantia, se fosse fácil de resolver provavelmente já teria sido resolvido, é muito mais provavel que isso exigirá muito tempo e não dependerá de apenas um grupo de pessoas especificas.

---

> 2. Sendo eleito moderador diamante, como atuará em relação a diversidade de pensamento considerando essas questões:
>
> - A SE não ouve a comunidade ou moderadores, você vai brigar com eles? Ou concorda com tudo o que eles fazem?
> - Outros moderadores já tem uma atuação conhecida. O que fará quando você pensar diferente? Se não conseguir convencer os demais que está certo, partirá para o conflito? Ou fará o que bem entender? Ou aceitará que sem consenso não pode atuar como quer?
> - Vai ouvir a comunidade ou fazer o que achar melhor unilateralmente? E quem é a comunidade para você? São os usuários ativos?
>
> Tente explicar o melhor que puder essa questão para conhecemos o que realmente importa, porque é só isso que está em jogo.

Não concordo com tudo que a SE (SO) faz, mas não vou brigar, nem teria sentido fazer isso, o foco dos moderadores é tentar fazer o melhor uso do que temos para a nossa comunidade e tentar argumentar com o que for possivel com a SO, brigar só iria causar problemas.

Sobre diferentes pensamentos farei o mesmo que já faço hoje como moderador comunitário, apresento meu ponto de vista da melhor forma possível e debatemos, com civilidade, conflitos não trazem benefícios, ideias diferentes muitas vezes ajudam a chegar a melhores resultados, portanto discordar as vezes é saudável.

Sobre ouvir a comunidade, irei ponderar entre ambos, ouvir a comunidade primeiro, refletir e claro pedir para que sejam pacientes, se não for um problema tão grave. A comunidade será os envolvidos diretamente no problema, moderadores e interessados que comentarem, não tem como exigir que 100% da comunidade atue sobre um problema especifico.

---

> 3. No final de 2019, a SE tomou atitudes e posturas que desagradaram grande parte de seus usuários, inclusive levando a renúncia em massa de diversos moderadores de diversos sites da rede. Qual é a sua postura quanto a esses eventos? Conhecendo esses eventos, como você pretende pautar seu relacionamento com a SE?

Apresentando minha opinião/visão aberta da melhor forma possível (geralmente no [META principal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)) de forma civilizada e sem dar abertura para conflitos com CMs, não acredito que renuncia seja a saída para problemas semelhantes, entendo que esses outros moderadores fizeram como uma forma de protesto, mas não o faria, pois meu compromisso não é com a SE e sim com a comunidade.

---

> 4. Uma reclamação frequente e antiga aqui no site é a falta de feedback ao OP em perguntas que tem problemas e são fechadas com pouco ou nenhum comentário destinado ao OP. Por outro lado, do ponto de vista de quem fecha as perguntas, ficar dando feedback inúmeras vezes para então ser atacado ou ser arrastado para debates intermináveis e improdutivos que dificilmente mudarão algo é uma atividade extremamente desgastante e desmotivadora. Qual é a sua opinião sobre isso? O que você fará quanto a isso?

Entrar em debates assim não é produtivo, não que não possamos dar um feedback, mas se os comentários se arrastarão para um debate acalorado, é melhor evitar, isso porque não creio que o papel do moderador seja dar um suporte 100% no problema do autor, toda comunidade deveria/poderia atuar mais nisso, temos muitas perguntas por dia, se todos nós como comunidade pudermos atuar melhor para ajudar as perguntas com problemas a ficarem boas, com certeza evitará esses desgastes.

---

> 5. "Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?"

Zelar pela comunidade com as ferramentas disponíveis, cuidar de problemas mais graves e eventualmente buscar meios de resolver problemas "macros" (que não são específicos) com novas ideias, geralmente com apoio dos usuários mais experientes e interessados na comunidade.

---

> 6. Você faria algo de diferente com relação a forma de comunicação da moderação atual com os demais usuários da comunidade?

Antes de serem moderadores somos todos usuários, eu raramente tive dificuldades em interagir com os moderadores, mesmo antes de me tornar moderador comunitário, creio que cada moderador seja uma pessoa impar, mas todos são abertos a algum dialogo, o que ocorre é que muitos debates já são coisas que foram debatidas muitas vezes e alguns usuários mais novos as vezes querem insistir em algo que já foi estudado e testado, ainda sim se eu notar que podemos melhorar a comunicação com certeza irei faze-lo.

---

> 7. O grande problema do site é a falta de moderação comunitária. Não há falta de moderação diamante, então de que maneiras você acredita que pode ajudar o site, como moderador, que não seriam possíveis com os privilégios de 10 ou 20 mil? Acha que pode acontecer o contrário e ajudar menos do que ajuda agora?

Concordo totalmente que isso é um problema, mas acredito que talvez os diamantes estejam sim um pouco sobrecarregados, eles tem feito o melhor possível, eu mesmo como comunitário tenho tentado ajudar ao máximo, existem situações aonde realmente algumas coisas precisam de mais agilidade, aonde o comunitário não tem poder, como fechamento ou reabertura imediata e problemas de SPAM, creio que existam tarefas que nós não vemos, mas estão lá e creio que eu poderei ajudar.

---

> 8. Você entende a diferença de uma "pergunta de helpdesk" (pergunta que basicamente só serve para o autor) para uma pergunta legitima e útil para comunidade (que agrega ao repositório de conhecimento, objetivo do site)? Se sim, explique seu ponto de vista.

Sim, o helpdek é exatamente isso, serve apenas para o autor e geralmente (nem sempre) esse tipo de pergunta carrega mais uma série de problemas, principalmente a dificuldade de reproduzir e poder ajudar o autor se torna uma tarefa quase impossível ou desgastante. As perguntas úteis geralmente são aquelas melhores elaboradas, que seguem o MCVE ou são busca de conhecimento técnico especifico de uma tecnologia ou linguagem e que geralmente são benéficas a todos interessados na mesma tecnologia.

---

> 9. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Dependendo da gravidade, estou bem certo que na moderação deve existir um meio oficial de lidar com o usuário sem expo-lo publicamente. Irei agir de maneira civilizada e tentar a comunicação, cada pessoa tem uma reação, independentemente disso, agirei de forma civilizada e para casos aonde não é possível remediar existe a suspensão temporária, que é um tempo para que o usuário reflita.

---

> 10. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Irei apresentar o meu ponto de vista técnico, de forma civilizada, mas não irei interferir diretamente, em alguns casos de for fechamento ou reabertura irei agir como usuário normal levando a pergunta para a fila (o que geralmente é semiautomático) e assim a comunidade poderá decidir com 5 votos, afinal de contas, a comunidade pode também analisar e decidir se um conteúdo é relevante

Comment: Na sua primeira resposta você diz "*creio que seja possível todos nós como comunidade atrair novamente os usuários mais interessados na qualidade*". Engajamento dos usuários tem sido realmente um problema grande na comunidade, principalmente nos últimos 2/3 anos. Você, como membro há 6 anos do site, site bem como é isso e como isso afeta a comunidade, bem como sabe todas as medidas que já foram postas em práticas para tentar aumentar o engajamento e construir uma comunidade melhor. [Continua]

Comment: [Continuação] Na prática podemos confirmar que o engajamento em si não melhorou nos últimos tempos. Cada vez menos temos usuários ativos e cada vez mais os que antes eram ativos acabam abandonando o site por desmotivação. Isto é, as ações recentes (e nem tão recentes assim) não ajudaram e nem estão ajudando tanto a comunidade como era planejado. Como moderador, o que pretenderia fazer para tentar mudar isso? Já teria algo em mente para melhorar o engajamento dos usuários?

Comment: @Woss infelizmente algo que as pessoas as vezes não notam é que o que atrai é marketing e publicada, podemos ter o melhor conteúdo, não vai ser motivo para atrair pessoas de interesse ou tornar os usuários mais participativos e como eu disse antes, independente de me tornar um moderador diamante eu já faço o possível dentro de meu alcance para incentivar contatos e divulgar em outras plataformas o site, inclusive comecei a participar de alguns outros site, indico respostas do site aqui para colegas de outras mídias [...]

Comment: [...] muitas situações dependem muito mais de nós como comunidade do que um ou poucos indivíduos, mas como eu disse, todos nós como comunidade deveríamos atuar assim, porque um "marketing pessoal" no seu próprio conteudo aqui poderia ajudar. Eu gostaria muito de ter um meio fácil de resolver isso, mas não é algo simples, é algo que dependerá de muitos fatores e que deveria ser de interesse de todos e não só de um tipo de usuário.

Comment: Gostaria de saber se o voto negativo é sobre as respostas ou é sobre o candidato por não concordar com a sua eleição.

Comment: Na pergunta 3, "*qual é a sua postura quanto a esses eventos?*" - Especificamente, sobre esses eventos, o que você pensa sobre eles? E para ser claro acerca do que são esses eventos, tem a ver com demissão sumária e sem aviso da Monica Cellio, novo código de conduta, comunidade LGBTQI+, marginalização da comunidade pela própria SE, pronomes, supressão de liberdade de expressão, um monte de ações que muitos classificam como mentiras, acusações, hipocrisia, caça as bruxas, etc. e um monte de outras coisas relacionadas. Como candidato, gostaria de saber o que você pensa sobre isso tudo.

Answer (score 7):

### Rebeca Nonato

> 1. Considerando que os votos são - ou pelo menos já foram - a segunda
>    coisa mais importante do site (a primeira são as perguntas e
>    respostas), como você vê o fato de que as pessoas hoje estão votando
>    menos que antigamente? Se você concorda que isso é um problema, qual
>    seria a solução? Mas se você acha que isso não é um problema, por
>    favor explique porquê. Só pra deixar claro que meu questionamento é
>    sobre a quantidade total de votos estar diminuindo. O fato de ter mais
>    negativos que positivos é um detalhe (claro que isso também pode ser
>    abordado, mas o ponto principal é que as pessoas de forma geral estão
>    votando menos, e quero saber o que os candidatos pensam sobre isso).

A comunidade de certa forma perdeu a visibilidade. A maioria iniciante na área só vem pelo que pode acontecer "de responderem meu trabalho de faculdade". Não vou negar, que no início eu vinha só para conseguir a "ajuda" no código. Porém, percebi que ela pode ser muito mais que isso. Mas, não vou negar que é bem difícil entender como funciona isso aqui. Acredito que podemos atrair mais os colaboradores, para interagir na comunidade, mas de certa forma, tentando facilitar o entendimento de como funciona.

> 2. Sendo eleito moderador diamante, como atuará em relação a diversidade
>    de pensamento considerando essas questões: A SE não ouve a comunidade
>    ou moderadores, você vai brigar com eles? Ou concorda com tudo o que
>    eles fazem?
>
>    - Outros moderadores já tem uma atuação conhecida. O que fará quando
>      você pensar diferente? Se não conseguir convencer os demais que está
>      certo, partirá para o conflito? Ou fará o que bem entender? Ou
>      aceitará que sem consenso não pode atuar como quer?
>    - Vai ouvir a comunidade ou fazer o que achar melhor unilateralmente? E
>      quem é a comunidade para você? São os usuários ativos?
>    - Tente explicar o melhor que puder essa questão para conhecemos o que
>      realmente importa, porque é só isso que está em jogo.

Acredito que o próprio nome comunidade já responde essa questão. Não somos uma comunidade se não agirmos em conjunto, e baseado em fatos, opiniões, entendimentos e consenso.
Vamos considerar a comunidade os ativos. E sim, irei ouvir, entender, assimilar, colocar a os fatos, opinião. E escolhermos o que for melhor para a comunidade. E não adianta brigar com a SE. Vamos seguir com a comunidade e o que pudermos fazer para melhorar cada vez mais.

> 3. No final de 2019, a SE tomou atitudes e posturas que desagradaram
>    grande parte de seus usuários, inclusive levando a renúncia em massa
>    de diversos moderadores de diversos sites da rede. Qual é a sua
>    postura quanto a esses eventos? Conhecendo esses eventos, como você
>    pretende pautar seu relacionamento com a SE?

Não tenho problema com a SE, meu compromisso é com a comunidade. Efetuar da melhor forma possível para executar as funções de moderador. Vamos seguindo.

> 4. Uma reclamação frequente e antiga aqui no site é a falta de feedback
>    ao OP em perguntas que tem problemas e são fechadas com pouco ou
>    nenhum comentário destinado ao OP. Por outro lado, do ponto de vista
>    de quem fecha as perguntas, ficar dando feedback inúmeras vezes para
>    então ser atacado ou ser arrastado para debates intermináveis e
>    improdutivos que dificilmente mudarão algo é uma atividade
>    extremamente desgastante e desmotivadora. Qual é a sua opinião sobre
>    isso? O que você fará quanto a isso?

Como disse no inicio. O site realmente é difícil para a cultura brasileira. Vamos ajudar nisso. Olha um vídeo legal e explicativo. https://hipsters.tech/como-funciona-o-stackoverflow/
Vamos ajudar a comunidade nessa ajuda. Isso me ajudou a entender o site. Vamos ajudar os outros colegas.

> 5. "Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?"

Vamos manter a comunidade da melhor forma possível, resolver os problemas maiores. Evitando virar um yahoo respostas. Firmado no compromisso.
Votar nas questões, bloquear publicações que não estejam de acordo com as regras da comunidade.

> 6. Você faria algo de diferente com relação a forma de comunicação da
>    moderação atual com os demais usuários da comunidade?

Não me vejo virar moderadora e sair modificando tudo. Vamos continuar a prontificar as ações para a melhoria constante.
Não tive problemas com a comunidade e nem com os moderadores. Só aperfeiçoando as ações e melhorias.

> 7. O grande problema do site é a falta de moderação comunitária. Não há
>    falta de moderação diamante, então de que maneiras você acredita que
>    pode ajudar o site, como moderador, que não seriam possíveis com os
>    privilégios de 10 ou 20 mil? Acha que pode acontecer o contrário e
>    ajudar menos do que ajuda agora?

Acredito que de forma a instigar os colegas a entender o funcionamento da comunidade. Como disse, eu mesmo já tive essa dificuldade, e foi grande.
Só agora consegui entender como funciona a comunidade. E a tarefas que a comunidade não tem ação. Como já fechar uma pergunta que é spam. Eu mesmo já votei várias vezes e a pergunta ficou lá. Mas, vamos melhorar isso cada vez mais.

> 8. Você entende a diferença de uma "pergunta de helpdesk" (pergunta que basicamente só serve para o autor) para uma pergunta legitima e útil para >     comunidade (que agrega ao repositório de conhecimento, objetivo do site)? Se sim, explique seu ponto de vista.

Sim. A pergunta que só serve para o autor, isso já diz tudo. Agora uma pergunta que serve para comunidade como um todo, é aquela com problemas mais genéricos, uma discussão mais ampla. Você vê essas perguntas até mesmo pelos votos que ela recebe.

> 9. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Como agimos com colegas de trabalho que são excelentes tecnicamente, mas difícil de relacionamento? Vamos conversar, entender suas questões, explicar a situação e tentar resolver. Acredito que as coisas se entendem. Porém, se necessário vamos agir conforme as normas e regras da comunidade.

> 10. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Conversar, apresentar argumentos técnicos, conforme regras da comunidade. E entender o outro lado. Não vejo porque de isso passar de um simples papo.

Comment: Na pergunta 3, "*qual é a sua postura quanto a esses eventos?*" - Especificamente, sobre esses eventos, o que você pensa sobre eles? E para ser claro acerca do que são esses eventos, tem a ver com demissão sumária e sem aviso da Monica Cellio, novo código de conduta, comunidade LGBTQI+, marginalização da comunidade pela própria SE, pronomes, supressão de liberdade de expressão, um monte de ações que muitos classificam como mentiras, acusações, hipocrisia, caça as bruxas, etc. e um monte de outras coisas relacionadas. Como candidata, gostaria de saber o que você pensa sobre isso tudo.

Comment: *[copiando um outro comentário daqui]* Gostaria de saber se o voto negativo é sobre as respostas ou é sobre a candidata por não concordar com a sua eleição.